# For which values are these two polynomial spaces in direct sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $V=\mathbb{R}[x]_{3}$ and $$V_h=Span(3x^2+2,(h-1)x,(h+2)x^3+1,3x^3+3x^2+(1-h)x+h+2)$$
and $$U_k= \{p(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]_{3}: p(x)=2p(x)+kxp'(x)+2kp(0)\}$$ be two subspaces of $V$.

For which values of $k$ and $h$ we have $V_h\oplus{U_k}=V$? Do I have to do a basis extraction?

Comment: do you mean: for which values of $h, k: \ V_h \oplus U_k = V$?

Comment: yes, sorry. I had to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to find $h, k$ as described, first you would need to find $h,k$ such that:

$V_h \cap U_k = \{0\}$. to prove that, let $x\in V_h\cap U_k$. let $x$ be a linear combination of both sets, and prove that $x$ must be the zero vector.

then, try to find the dimenstions of each sub-vector space. in order for $V_h \oplus U_k = V$, then $\dim V = \dim V_h + \dim U_k$.

then, you will have to prove that for every $v\in V$ there exists $v_1 \in V_h, u_1 \in U_K: \ v_1 + u_1 = v$.

this might be a little hard, so instead you may prove that every vector in $V_h$ (or in $U_k$)  is a Subtraction of vector in $V$ and a vector that belongs to the other sub-space.

Comment: I tried to find a basis for $V_h+U_k$ but you get a matrix made up of 8 columns and 4 rows and it's really hard to use the Gaussian reduction... For the intersection I found the values of the two parameters such that any vector of the span of $V_h$ cannot  be written as a vector of $U_k$